# Navigating through the directory stack in zsh from the command line

Tags: zsh

In zsh, is there a way to navigate through the **history of directories** that I have visited (those listed in dirs) **when I am typing a command in the command line**?

For example, say that I start typing `cp -r` in the terminal, I would like to then use  `M-n` or `M-p` until I  find a directory, from the list of directories that I have visited, that I want to follow `cp -r` in the command that I am typing.  Eventually I would find `/some/path/` for the `cp` source directory, and then type `<SPC>` and repeat the process to find `/some/other/path` for the `destination directory` for my `cp` command.

In case it helps, the code below helps me navigate my **command history** from the command line using `C-n` and `C-p`, which allows me to autocomplete my command with other commands that I previously typed.

```
up-line-or-history-beginning-search () {
  if [[ -n $PREBUFFER ]]; then
    zle up-line-or-history
  else
    zle history-beginning-search-backward
  fi
}
down-line-or-history-beginning-search () {
  if [[ -n $PREBUFFER ]]; then
    zle down-line-or-history
  else
    zle history-beginning-search-forward
  fi
}

zle -N up-line-or-history-beginning-search
zle -N down-line-or-history-beginning-search

bindkey '^P' up-line-or-history-beginning-search
bindkey '^N' down-line-or-history-beginning-search
```

Comment: `cd -<TAB>` if you have pushd enabled?

Comment: @UlrichDangel That is very close to what I want! There are two differences: 1) I think it only shows directories within my current session and 2) It doesn't let me iterate pass the last item in the list. Is there any alternative?

Comment: no, but you can increase the stacksize